# why does google datastore second query returns modified instance (without calling put after first query)?

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb, google-cloud-datastore

I'm running into a very counter-intuitive situation with querying datastore.

here are the steps:

1. retrieve object with first query: `list_objects = MyModel.query(cls.name == name).fetch()`
2. modify the list_objects: `for o in list_objects: o.value = new_value`
3. retrieve the object 2nd-time: `list_objects_2 = MyModel.query(cls.name == name).fetch()`
4. now all all objects in list_objects_2 have new_value, although in step 2, a put was never called to actually modify the datastore, and I checked my datastore in between, and the value is the original value
5. modify list_objects_2: `for o in list_objects_2: o.value = new_new_value`, and now list_objects1 all have new_new_value

I also tried with `fetch(keys_only = True)` and `k.get()`, but same issue.

my impression is that query is against the actual datastore, why does it keep returning the same instances instead of constructing new ones? is it due to caching of some sort?

Comment: Does not sound right, can you give reproducible example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout this article https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/cache

> The in-context cache is fast; this cache lives in memory. When an NDB
>   function writes to the Datastore, it also writes to the in-context
>   cache. When an NDB function reads an entity, it checks the in-context
>   cache first. If the entity is found there, no Datastore interaction
>   takes place.
>
> When an NDB function queries the Datastore, the result list is
>   retrieved from the Datastore. However, if any individual result is in
>   the in-context cache, it is used in place of the value retrieved from
>   the Datastore query. Query results are written back to the in-context
>   cache if the cache policy says so (but never to Memcache).

1) `list_objects = MyModel.query(cls.name == name).fetch()`

warms up in-context cache

2) `for o in list_objects: o.value = new_value`

modifies objects in memory only

3) `list_objects_2 = MyModel.query(cls.name == name).fetch()`

actually no datastore interaction takes place, u get same objects from cache

4) `for o in list_objects_2: o.value = new_new_value`

modifies objects in memory only

5) `fetch(keys_only = True)` and `k.get()` no datastore interaction takes place

Comment: thanks! this is the case. I figured this out after trial and error, it's related to in-process caching, if I add fetch(use_cache=False), then the query returns new instances, although I'm a bit surprised why the in-process caching is turned on by default.